# Seltzer Water or Carbonated Water in my 6v. Golf Cart Batteries

Tags: battery

I was told that I Could use Seltzer Water or Carbonated Water in my 6v. Golf Cart Batteries, is that true?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! These are wet cell batteries? You're suggesting to put this *inside the battery* to replace any fluid which is missing?

Comment: Who told you this? I'd suggest not listening to *anything* that they say in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Not a good idea.  Seltzer is acidic and will change the ph of your electrolyte.  You should use distilled water only.  Follow the instructions for your brand of battery. Be careful.  Battery acid is dangerous.

Comment: The carbon dioxide gas itself won't do any damage, but most commercial brands of carbonated water also contain sodium and potassium salts which will affect the chemical reactions inside the battery. Whether it would be better or worse than using tap water of unknown quality is a good question, but the best advice is "don't do it".